# Can we use buttons instead of collection view?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to ios programming. I was wondering if it will make any difference if i use Collection of buttons with images on it instead of collection view. I need collection view to select a particular option and start a new view. I was thinking if i could do the same using buttons arranged like a grid.Will it make any significant difference?

Comment: alternate way , you can use the ***didSelectItemAt*** or ***TapGesture*** for your concept

Comment: @Madhu You can use Buttons instead of UICollectionView but If you use buttons then you have to right a lot of code. UICollectionView will make your life simpler. What's the issue in using UICollectionView?

Comment: Coder is right, by taking separate buttons you have to manage each button individually. But in collectionView you have to manage single array.

Comment: 1. You need to play a lot with constraints of buttons if you app supports for both orientation. 
2. You can’t  do add and remove buttons dynamically.
3. You can’t move item to different places in your view if needed. etc..
A lot more challenges will be there if you use buttons instead of `collection view`. My suggestion is go with `UICollectionView` for how items in grid form.

Comment: @Coder As I am new to ios programming it is getting little bit difficult at this point of time to work with CollectionView and grasp the concept.So i thought about buttons as it seemed easier to work with. Anyways I will definitely consider the suggestion given by you and others. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

It’s completely depends on your UI how it look like, there is a table view and you are displaying two or three images on the row, then it is fine you can use buttons, but there are number of images in row or you are doing number of image like Photo Gallery, then you have to use Collection view, that is more batter manage collection of images, asynchronous load image, your UI will not be hang etc…

As my suggestion is using Collection view is more better then UIButton, while you are doing more images…

I hope you can get my point

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can use `UIButtons` instead of `UICollectionView`. But remember both have its own functionalities. if your data is non consistent then its a headache to use a `UIButton`, But `UICollectionView` itself recognised the data we want to populate and arrange itself according to the data.

For the recommendation `UICollectionView` is a batter approach for it as compare to `UIButtons`

Answer (score 0):

If you have dynamic data or large data my recommendation is `UICollectionView`, Because `UICollectionView` itself recognised the data populate accordingly through its `Delegate` and `DataSource` ...

Refer [UICollectionViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate) and [UICollectionViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource)  here

And you want customise your Cell you can do that with [UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout?language=objc)

And you have very small number of Static data just go with `UIButton`.

But my preference for all this scenario is `UICollectionView`